# Connecting to MemSQL from PHP codeigniter application

Tags: php, codeigniter, database-connection, singlestore

[MemSQL is new](http://developers.memsql.com/). Stackoverflow did not return any search result with the keyword 'MemSQL'. MemSQL claims absolute similarity to MySQL, except that MemSQL is 30 times faster. I was just studying MemSQL and stumbled on this thought. Unable to try it out yet, but I have a very basic question related to DataBaseConnector.

There is no particular instruction that i could find regarding how to connect an existing PHP app with MySQL SQLs to a MemSQL database. However, [this MemSQL page](http://developers.memsql.com/docs/1b/guides/from_mysql.html) says:

> To transition your application, simply change the connection
>   credentials to point to MemSQL.

Now can anyone with experience clarify if I change only the port number to my MemSQL service, then all the currently written SQLs would work fine as they used to work with MySQL? Will it also be able to work with the currently written Active-Records statements in my codeigniter app?

***[p.s. given that I have exported my data from MySQL and import my data to MemSQL as instructed in the same page.]***

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<pre>';
mysql_connect(":var/lib/memsql-ops/data/=memsql.sock",'root','');

$q = mysql_query('SHOW DATABASES;');

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($q, MYSQL_ASSOC) ) :
    print_r($row);
endwhile;
```

Answer (score 0):

In theory it should.

Take a look here to see all the supported/unsupported commands

http://developers.memsql.com/docs/1b/

The one big downside i can see so far is there is a limit 2 two table joins per statement.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby active record works with MemSQL. You can use mysqldump to port the data over.